# Why can't gif images copy at a reasonable speed on this dell laptop with XP?

Tags: windows-xp, file-transfer, gif

I've got this somewhat old Dell Latitude D810.  Strangest thing... If I try to copy anything that has gif files in it the gif files take forever.  Like a few minutes per gif regardless of size.

Everything else copies fine.

I notice this when copying files off our network, copying off multiple external drives, and even when files are copying during an installation process.

I'm on Windows XP Pro service pack 3.

I've never seen anything like this before.  Anyone else?

Comment: Your computer is opening each GIF to see if it is funny. Computers don't have a lot of fun, let it enjoy what it can.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using list or thumbnail view in your explorer?  This could be possibly caused by viewing your directories in thumbnail view, as windows is generating the thumbnail, it puts a lock on the file it's creating a thumbnail of, and explorer is waiting for these resources to be unlocked.

Comment: The view does not seem to affect it.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I think of is that an antivirus program is scanning the files when you copy them, but is doing so inefficiently.